# Is there a denoiser with GLSL for mpv?

Tags: glsl, mpv

It would be great to just put a GLSL shader in configs that will denoise a video.

I tried putting the line "denoise=1" in mpv.conf but it didn't work: on Windows 10 "Error parsing option denoise (option not found)". With Linux I don't remember if there was an error, but I couldn't see anything noticeble.

Comment: Did you get any solution so far?

Comment: No, i'm sorry. Let us know if you find anything.